# How do you craft the Portable Refiner in No Man's Sky Next?

Tags: no-mans-sky

Not sure if my game is bugged, but I have no option under my exosuit, spaceship, or multi tool to build the portable refiner.

I've checked the technology and craft product sections.

Is there a quest or something I need to locate before I can build this technology?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are on console, press up on your D-Pad while on foot (I believe it is <kbd>Z</kbd> on PC).  This opens the build menu.  Within that menu, you should be able to find the Portable Refiner.

Additional [Source](https://www.vg247.com/2018/07/25/no-mans-sky-next-third-person-refiner-sky-fleet-command-room/) and information:

> To build a Refiner, you have to open the Build Menu while on foot (press up on the d-pad on console). The Refiner is about the fourth one to the right.

You will need a Metal Plate and 30 oxygen to build the refiner.  You will also need fuel to power it (like carbon).

I do not think the blueprint is locked behind a quest, but I do know it was needed to repair one of your ships broken components when you first start a new game with the Next update.  When I played the other night, that is when I built my refiner.  I assume when you reach that point for repairing your ship, the blueprint will be unlocked for you if it is indeed locked to begin with.

Comment: This was the problem. I was looking at the D-Pad down arrow :) I found it while pressing the D-Pad up arrow. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Ate you at a base. If so it's in the base building menu under equipment. Then go to portable equipment and you should see it. If not at a base it slylybe party of your quick menu when you push dpad up